# Sqitch throws fe_sendauth (no password) error with sqitch

Tags: android, postgresql, rest, sqitch

I am trying to use [PostgREST](https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest) and [sqitch](https://github.com/theory/sqitch) on Debian (Wheezy) to provide a REST API for an Android app which queries a Postgres DB, [like in this example](http://blog.jonharrington.org/postgrest-introduction/).

I've written SQL to create the tables, however when I issue the `sqitch deploy` command (as in the example, with everything working until that point), I get an error:

`fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

There is neither a password in the example or in the accepted parameters of the `sqitch deploy` command. When I search on the error I find a [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996957/fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied) suggesting to try `pg_ctl reload`, however that doesn't work in this case.

The problem persists regardless of if I am logged in as `postgres`, `root`, or some other privileged user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to put your password in to a `~/.pgpass` file. But there are other ways to go about it, too. See [sqitch-authentication](https://github.com/theory/sqitch/blob/master/lib/sqitch-authentication.pod) for the various ways to supply passwords to Sqitch.

Comment: Thank you! Always nice when the developer takes time to help you. Much appreciated.

Comment: @theory try to add file with windows but not working too

Comment: @HudaTwfik Could be a permission issue; be sure to follow all the steps documented for [the password file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html)