# Yii2 postgres error - fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: postgresql, yii2

I use Yii2, db connection

```
'db' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=data-storage',
    'username' => 'data-storage',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
]
```

My database does not have a password. I got an error: **SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied**.
If I use some password (just fake, as I mentioned I don't have it) I'm getting: **password authentication failed for user "data-storage"**

In pg_hba.conf I have a record for my domain:
 `host all all 172.28.3.70/32 trust`
Which works fine for PgAdmin.

Comment: helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996957/fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I have used **localhost** instead of the **server IP** where the database is located.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name', 
        'username' => 'db_username',
        'password' => NULL,
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'schemaMap' => [
          'pgsql'=> [
            'class'=>'yii\db\pgsql\Schema',
            'defaultSchema' => 'public' //specify your schema here
          ]
        ], // PostgreSQL
    ];
```

or remove `password`.