# Rails spec test error, no password supplied

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec

I have an existing project, with created many years ago. No one at out company has succeeded in running them.  I have updated files to fit the latest rails version but when I run bundle exec rspec spec/models/promo_code_spec.rb,

I get

```
   /Users/mmiller/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `initialize': fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

I have followed these steps in this post:
    [fe_sendauth: no password supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996957/fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied)
but still getting the same error. 
Any advice on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: please show database part in your yml. Do you know your username and password?..

Answer (score 0):

Change this,

```
local   all             all                                     trust
```

to,

```
local   all             all                                     md5
```

and create a super_user in PostgreSQL with username and password, and add that username and password to your database.yml file

Answer (score 0):

Welp, for my case, as a complete new user of Rails testing of any kind, I got this error when I wanted to use RSpec and forgot to create a test database. Make sure your test db has been assigned its own name in database.yml.

One helpful SO post mentioned this command line to get things initialized:

```
bundle exec rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test
```

Then on to joy...