# Could not connect to the primary server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, patroni

I am going to do Patroni Cluster with 4 nodes.
2 nodes are patroni (07,08)
1 node is haproxy(06)
1 node is etcd (05)

08 node is successfully joind the cluster. But 07 node is getting this error. (Versions:  PostgreSQL 12.13, ubuntu 20.04)

```sql
postgres@07:~$ pg_ctl restart
waiting for server to shut down.... done
server stopped
waiting for server to start....2023-02-24 12:41:27.350 +03 [484335] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.13 (Ubuntu 12.13-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, 64-bit
2023-02-24 12:41:27.350 +03 [484335] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "10.3.3.197", port 5432
2023-02-24 12:41:27.351 +03 [484335] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-02-24 12:41:27.372 +03 [484336] LOG:  database system was shut down in recovery at 2023-02-24 12:41:27 +03
2023-02-24 12:41:27.372 +03 [484336] LOG:  entering standby mode
2023-02-24 12:41:27.375 +03 [484336] LOG:  redo starts at 0/3000718
2023-02-24 12:41:27.375 +03 [484336] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/3000800
2023-02-24 12:41:27.375 +03 [484336] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/3000800: wanted 24, got 0
2023-02-24 12:41:27.376 +03 [484335] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2023-02-24 12:41:27.384 +03 [484340] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
2023-02-24 12:41:27.390 +03 [484341] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
 done
server started
postgres@07:~$ 2023-02-24 12:41:32.392 +03 [484372] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
2023-02-24 12:41:37.418 +03 [484403] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
2023-02-24 12:41:42.399 +03 [484434] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
...
```

After making changes to the pg_hba.conf or postgresql.conf files, the cluster needs to be reloaded to pick up the changes.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996957/fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied)

- From the command line: pg_ctl reload
- From within a db (as superuser): select pg_reload_conf();

But I am still getting this error.

Comment: You have to configure `pg_hba.conf` on the primary server so that it allows the standby to connect.

Comment: It needs a password, but wasn't given one.  We don't know what you want to happen.  Is it supposed to not need a password?  Is supposed to be have been given a password?  You said you made changes to pg_hba.conf, but tell us what those changes were.