# Postgresql & RoR issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm having issues installing the **SOLIDUS** gem for my rails app. I followed the instructions from [GitHub](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus) but when i run the command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` i get the error:

```
mannay:testsite mannay$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've tried adding `username: mannay` to my database.yml and even `password:` but it doesn't work. I thought maybe i've added a password that i don't remember, so i opened postgressapp, and tested

```
ALTER USER mannay with password 'new_password';
```

but it doesn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: See if any of this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094845/how-do-i-get-my-rails-app-to-use-my-postgresql-db, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971101/how-do-i-start-enterpisedb-postgresql-on-mac-osx-10-6-8  -- I solved the fe_sendauth error by making some changes to  the `pg_hba.conf` file.

Comment: did you set the same password in your `config/database.yml`?